# WeakReference on Demand

Tags: c#, .net

I have an complex class from TypeA (TypeA hasn't been created by me).

```
class TypeA { }
```

These Objects is held by different classes I don't have access to:

```
class TypeB { private TypeA TypeAObject; } 
class TypeC { private TypeA TypeAObject; }
```

I have a reference to TypeA in my Own Class, too.

```
class MyClass { private TypeA TypeAObject; }
```

Now i have the following problem. If my class is collected from the garbage collection TypeAObject is not freed because there is still a reference by TypeB and TypeC on the TypeAObject.

For this problem I thought WeakReferenc would be the solution:

```
class MyClass { private WeakReference<TypeA> TypeAObject; }
```

That worked long time as expected but somtimes TypeB or TypeC need the Object from TypeA. For this problem I thought there is a solution, too. TypeA Objects have an Unloaded event that I can use. After this point nobody uses the object again. So I just set the Object from TypeA to a WeakReference in the unloaded event.

```
class MyClass 
{ 
  private TypeA TypeAObject;
  private WeakReference<TypeA> TypeAObjectWeak;

  public void SetUnloaded()
  {
        TypeAObject.Unloaded = () => {TypeAObjectWeak = new WeakReference<TypeA>(TypeAObject) };
  }

}
```

But the TypeAObject isn't collected. That's now what my question is: Is there a way to set an Object to WeakReference on demand?

**Edit**

The Class TypeA is in my case a class of type WorkflowApplication
(http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/WorkflowApplication.cs,533e298006a3d9ca)

=> The problem were the events of the WorkflowApplication (i.a. UnhandledException, Idle,...). After setting them to null the object was collected.

Comment: How would a `WeakReference` from `MyClass` help, if it's `TypeB` and `TypeC` that are holding onto the references for `TypeA`? You need to work out how to either clear those references, or ensure that the `TypeB` and `TypeC` objects are eligible for garbage collection too. Unfortunately we can't really help you do that.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to control this? Is it a problem that the object is still in memory because some other objects (of type TypeB or TypeC) are still alive?

Comment: There are ways to handle such things although there is no way for us to say whether they're safe with so little / generic information. For instance, if the object is accessed through an interface in those types you could build your own implementation of that interface that holds the actual (expensive?) object. This would allow you to control the lifetime of this (expensive) object even though TypeB and TypeC still has a reference to your interface implementation (wrapper) object.

Comment: The problem were the events of the WorkflowApplication (i.a. UnhandledException, Idle,...). After setting them to null the object was collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that without changing TypeB or TypeC to also use weak references.

Imagine you having a class where someone else is allowed to just say "Sorry, you're no longer allowed to hold a reference to this object" even though you specifically has hidden all access to the reference to that object. That would be bad.

And so you can't do that.

A `WeakReference` is not something that impacts the object at all, it's just a different way to hold a reference to an object. Any non-weak references are just as strong as before, even if you start using weak references elsewhere.

Consider it like this. I have the address to my house stored in my contact list on my phone, and I have registered it with the county so that they know who lives there. The fact that you wrote down my address on a postit note and subsequently lost that note does not in any way change my or the counties reference to my house. It only impacted the reference you had yourself.

Answer (score -3):

You still have a strong reference to the object in TypeAObject. Set it to null, and it should be collected.

If you just want the object to be collected, why do you need the weak reference?

Comment: This is not the issue, the reference is held by other instances not under control by the OP